# PHP DateTime - modify reference

Tags: php, datetime, reference

I'm trying to modify a DateTime object in a function passed as an reference:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2012-02-12');

for($n1 = 0; $n1 < 10; $n1++) {
    $date->modify('first day of next month');
    setDate($date, 15);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "<br />\n";
}

function setDate(&$date, $day) {
    $date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'),  $day);
}
?>
```

But the result is not as expected. Did I got something wrong with this references stuff?

EDIT:
Expected result:
2012-03-15
2012-04-15
...

Result with function above:
2012-03-01
2012-04-01
...

Comment: what is your result / expected result?

Comment: I think the issue is that the results always show the first of the month. It looks as though the code should set the date to the first of the next month, then set the date to the 15th. But when you output the date, it's the first, not the 15th. Seems like once you use a relative statement _first day of next month_, then it's _stuck_ on the first. You can't change the date with setDate. You can change the month/year, but not the date.

Comment: It seems to me that `DateTime::setDate` does not work after the date has already been set. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, and it seems to fail silently. Odd.

Comment: That's not correct. Changing the date with setDate is possible on the same objects mutliple times. Have a look at Example #2 at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My PHP didn't like the 'first day of nest month' bit, but worked with '+1 month'. Since you are setting the day absolutely I wouldn't worry about it not being on the first. Or if it needs to be you can set it to the first before you go into the loop.

So, this worked for me. I added the `new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')` so it would stop bugging me about it not being set (shared server.) And removed the pass by reference (`&`) bit since all objects are passed by reference by default in PHP now.

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('2012-02-12',new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
    for($n1 = 0; $n1 < 10; $n1++) {
        $date->modify('+1 month');
        setDate($date, 15);
        echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "<br />\n";
    }
    function setDate($date, $day) {
        $date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'),  $day);
    }
?>
```

Comment: It seems like the 'first day of next month' is the problem. Strange. Changing it to '+1 month' in my code is resulting in getting the right result. There's a disadvantage in this way: adding one month to the 2012-01-31 is resulting in 2012-03-02. Therefore the result of the function will be 2012-03-15 instead of 2012-02-15. But it'll work with calling function setDate once with day = 1, adding 1 month and then again call function setDate with 15.

Answer (score 2):

You are already passing a reference to the DateTime object. There is no need to pass an instance of DateTime implicitly as a reference. If you need a copy of the DateTime object, you will need to use `clone` keyword.

As far as the result, it iterates over 15th of every sequential month, which, reading the code, I expected to be the outcome.